# finding exponential generating function by recursion in order to find the formal power series

Tags: combinatorics

If i define the number of permutation on n objects with order that divides 2 i get the recursion:
a(n+2)=a(n+1)+(n+1)*a(n).
then i can get the exponential generating function 
i(x)=sum(a(n)/n!*x^n)=exp(x+0.5x^2)

now, is there any way to get the formal power series 
f(x)=sum(a(n)*x^n)
by this?

Comment: Probably not. This is [OEIS A$000085$](http://oeis.org/A000085), which does not seem to have a nice ordinary generating function.